# findAll() method of CrudRepository is returning null values

Tags: java, crud, spring-data-redis

I am working with Spring data Redis and have the following repository:

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, String> {
}
```

When I call `findAll(Iterable< String> ids)` method, correct data is returned:

```
final List<String> ids = Lists.newArrayList("id1", "id2");
final Iterable<MyClass> mappingIterable = mappingRepository.findAll(ids);
```

However, calling `findAll()` is not returning data, instead it returns `null` value against each of the `id` present in Redis:

```
final Iterable<MyClass> mappingIterable = mappingRepository.findAll();
```

Returns:

> [null, null]

Comment: ehm ... what is the difference between those two calls? you posted the same call twice.

Comment: What is different between those calls. Second one not have ids List so u dont declare null return to you

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry, pls check now

Comment: @Er.Er Can you kindly check now and elaborate your answer little more?

Comment: I couldn't see an usage like that on [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  i think u have to send a list in findall()

Comment: so then findAll(ids); shouldn't be work. it should be findAllById(ids); so something wrong :D

Comment: @Er.Er, Please check this one:
https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: Are you by any chance using Mocks? I just encountered the same scenario in a JUnit test. My repository was a mock and I resolved the issue by initialising the mock to return a `Set` when the `findAll()` method was called.

Comment: Seems a bug in Spring Data Redis: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-570

Comment: As of december 2018, I am having the same issue. Has anyone been able to fix?

Comment: Which version of spring, and dependencies?

Comment: it's March 2020, the bug is still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

You may try to replace a normal List with ArrayList, which will make it easier to create and update, if your project doesn't require to use just List. It may not work, but could make your work easier. Anyways, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried passing an empty list as parameter ? you can try:

```
repo.findAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

I suspect that you need to override findAll with no parameters yet I am not sure about that.

Answer (score -1):

did you try findAllById(Iterable ids)
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAllById-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: This is basically the same method that works for the question author. What he wants is to get all the records, not filtering by any list of known ids.